# How to execute a task after the deployment phase in Maven?

Tags: java, maven

I want to rename the local ZIP file after it was deployed to a repository.
Some plugin/action has to run after the "distributionManagement" section was processed. 
Does anybody know how this can be achieved?

Comment: What kind of problem are you trying to solve? After an artifact is deployed to remote repository everything is done?

Comment: The zip created by the package process contains the version number in its name. That is ok for the deployment phase but for a post processing tool the zip file name should not contain the version number.

Comment: What should be post processed cause the zip file will be deployed into remote repository. So deployment to other things should be done from remote repository. Otherwise you are coupling your build process with some other processes ?

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you either have a very strange setup, or you're doing something wrong.

Regardless, if you really want to run stuff after deploy, I suggest attaching your plugin to the `deploy` phase, and place it after the deploy plugin declaration (you can insert a blank declaration of the deploy plugin, just to make sure maven sees the correct order).
My understanding is that Maven runs the plugins it encounters in the same phase, in the order of their definition.